# Subversion Lost Track of Deleted Files

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, ankhsvn

I've been doing a lot of cleanup on a large solution controlled via Subversion.  We use the AnkhSVN plugin for Visual Studio support.  I had to restart my machine for unrelated reasons, and after returning to Visual Studio, all the deleted files have disappeared from the Pending Changes window.  The various project files where the files were are still showing as modified, but I fear that when I check in the changes, the files I deleted will not be deleted from the repository.  The deleted files are still deleted from my local machine, and are not showing up in Solution Explorer, but when I browse the SVN repo, they are (obviously) still shown there.  How can I force SVN to take a closer look at my working copy and see that I've deleted the files?